# Unable using PyTest and GetText, _ not available

Tags: python, gettext, pytest

I'm trying to write unit tests for my application.

Unfortunately I am having some trouble with gettext.

When I run my soft from `main.py` everything is ok, labels are translated ...

In my main I run :

```
language = gettext.translation("NAME_SOFTWARE", locale_dir, languages=[default_locale])
language.install()
```

But when I run unit tests (PyTest) the tests fail because the '_' doesn't exist. 
Exception :

```
create_document Exception : name '_' is not defined, in ...
```

So I understand that when I run the app from my tests, the language isn't initialized and _ doesn't exist.

I tried to add :

```
from gettext import gettext
_ = gettext
```

in my files, but it's dirty and it doesn't work.

The gettext documentation say to use :

```
import gettext
t = gettext.translation('mymodule', ...)
_ = t.gettext
```

I don't have the last line, but it seem to work without it (at least when I launch the app from main.py).

How could I make it work ?

Comment: Can you share your pytest code?